# 2D random walk, python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-requests, 2d

I have trouble writing this code. 2D random walk. A two dimensional random walk simulates the behavior of a particle moving in a grid of points. At each step, the random walker moves north, south, east, or west with probability 1/4, independently of previous moves. Compose a program that takes a command-line argument n and estimates how long it will take a random walker to hit the boundary of a 2n+1-by-2n+1 square centered at the starting point.

This is all the code I wrote.

```
    import sys
    import stdio
    import random

    # the size of the box, which should be 4
    n = int(sys.argv[1])

    # should be the amount of steps taken to reach the boundary/ end of the box.
    c = int(sys.argv[2])

    def random_walk_2D (n):
    x, y = 0, 0
    i = 4
   North = 1; South = 2; West = 3; East = 4

    for i in range(n):

    people = random.randint(1,4)

    while I < c:
    stdio.write(

    if people == 1:
    y = y + 1
    elif people == 2:
    y = y - 1
    elif people == 3:
    x = x + 1
    else :
    x = x - 1
    return (x, y)

    sdio.write('The walker took ')
    stdio.write(c)
    stdio.write(' steps. ')
```

I also need to add a while-loop but I can't out where it goes. I need help. Thanks for your response

Comment: What is wrong with your indentation?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: If you do not properly indent the code, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: A recent discussion have fast implementation on a grid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246926/average-time-to-hit-a-given-line-on-2d-random-walk-on-a-unit-grid/69247561#69247561

Answer (score 1):

```
def random_walk_2d(n):
    xy = 0+0j
    cnt = 0
    while(np.abs(np.real(xy)) < n or np.abs(np.imag(xy)) < n):
        xy += np.random.choice([1j,-1j, 1, -1])
        cnt += 1

    return cnt

def simulate(N_sims,n):
    expected_move = 0
    for i in range(N_sims):
        expected_move += random_walk_2d(n)

    return expected_move/N_sims
```