# Average time to hit a given line on 2D random walk on a unit grid

Tags: python, simulation, probability, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to simulate the following problem:

Given a 2D random walk (in a lattice grid) starting from the origin what is the average waiting time to hit the line y=1-x

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
N=5*10**3
results=[]
for _ in tqdm(range(N)):
  current = [0,0]
  step=0
  while (current[1]+current[0] != 1):
    step += 1
    a = np.random.randint(0,4)
    if (a==0):
      current[0] += 1
    elif (a==1):
      current[0] -= 1
    elif (a==2):
      current[1] += 1
    elif (a==3):
      current[1] -= 1
  results.append(step)
```

This code is slow even for N<10**4 I am not sure how to optimize it or change it to properly simulate the problem.

Comment: one way would be to use complex numbers or vectors to store x and y together instead of a 2 element list, then something like `pos += random.choice([1,-1,1j,-1j])` would let you get around conditionals then use `pos.real` and `pos.imag`

Comment: is the point of the exercise to simulate a bunch of walks or is it to calculate mathematically what the average is? just making sure your not totally going in the wrong direction

Comment: Mathematically the answer is infinite, so I guess it doesn't make much sense simulating it (at least in this way)

Comment: the average time before you reach the line can't be infinite, half the time you get there with the first step, if you stepped away there is a quarter of a chance you'd get there with the next 2 steps... I think there'd be a converging series that will have some finite average but you are right that occasionally it does take infinitely long to actually reach the line.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Isn't it actually a 1D problem? With each step we have a 50% change to get 1 step closer to the goal and a 50% chance to get 1 step further away from the goal. Or am I just too tired to think straight? :-)

Comment: You are right https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254905/random-walk-2d-average-time-to-hit-line/4254913#4254913

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode you are correct, realizing the move `(1,0)` is equivelent to `(0,-1)` might help speed up simulation, but assuming there are similar questions like how far do you end up from the origin on average when you arrive at the line would require a general 2d approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of simulating a bunch of random walks sequentially, lets try simulating multiple paths at the same time and tracking the probabilities of those happening, for instance we start at position `0` with probability 1:

```
states = {0+0j: 1}
```

and the possible moves along with their associated probabilities would be something like this:

```
moves = {1+0j: 0.25,  0+1j: 0.25, -1+0j: 0.25, 0-1j: 0.25}
# moves = {1: 0.5, -1:0.5} # this would basically be equivelent
```

With this construct we can update to new states by going over the combination of each state and each move and update probabilities accordingly

```
def simulate_one_step(current_states):
    newStates = {}
    for cur_pos, prob_of_being_here in current_states.items():
        for movement_dist,prob_of_moving_this_way in moves.items():
            newStates.setdefault(cur_pos+movement_dist, 0)
            newStates[cur_pos+movement_dist] += prob_of_being_here*prob_of_moving_this_way
    return newStates
```

Then we just iterate this popping out all winning states at each step:

```
for stepIdx in range(1, 100):
    states = simulate_one_step(states)
    winning_chances = 0
    # use set(keys) to make copy so we can delete cases out of states as we go.
    for pos, prob in set(states.items()):
        # if y = 1-x
        if pos.imag == 1 - pos.real:
            winning_chances += prob
            # we no longer consider this a state that propogated because the path stops here.
            del states[pos]
    
    print(f"probability of winning after {stepIdx} moves is: {winning_chances}")
```

you would also be able to look at `states` for an idea of the distribution of possible positions, although totalling it in terms of distance from the line simplifies the data. Anyway, the final step would be to average the steps taken by the probability of taking that many steps and see if it converges:

```
total_average_num_moves += stepIdx * winning_chances
```

But we might be able to gather more insight by using symbolic variables! (note I'm simplifying this to a 1D problem which I describe how at the bottom)

```
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol("x") # will sub in 1/2 later
moves = {
    1: x, # assume x is the chances for us to move towards the target
   -1: 1-x # and therefore 1-x is the chance of moving away
}
```

This with the exact code as written above gives us this sequence:

```
probability of winning after 1 moves is: x
probability of winning after 2 moves is: 0
probability of winning after 3 moves is: x**2*(1 - x)
probability of winning after 4 moves is: 0
probability of winning after 5 moves is: 2*x**3*(1 - x)**2
probability of winning after 6 moves is: 0
probability of winning after 7 moves is: 5*x**4*(1 - x)**3
probability of winning after 8 moves is: 0
probability of winning after 9 moves is: 14*x**5*(1 - x)**4
probability of winning after 10 moves is: 0
probability of winning after 11 moves is: 42*x**6*(1 - x)**5
probability of winning after 12 moves is: 0
probability of winning after 13 moves is: 132*x**7*(1 - x)**6
```

And if we ask [the OEIS what the sequence `1,2,5,14,42,132...` means it tells us those are Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C14%2C42%2C132&language=english&go=Search) with the formula of `(2n)!/(n!(n+1)!)` so we can write a function for the non-zero terms in that series as:

```
f(n,x) = (2n)! / (n! * (n+1)!) * x^(n+1) * (1-x)^n
```

or in actual code:

```
import math
def probability_of_winning_after_2n_plus_1_steps(n, prob_of_moving_forward = 0.5):
    return (math.factorial(2*n)/math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(n+1) 
           * prob_of_moving_forward**(n+1) * (1-prob_of_moving_forward)**n)
```

which now gives us a relatively instant way of calculating relevant parameters for any length, or more usefully [ask wolfram alpha what the average would be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D0+to+infinity+of+%282n%2B1%29+*+%282n%29%21+%2F+%28n%21+*+%28n%2B1%29%21%29+*+0.5%5E%282n%2B1%29) (it diverges)

---

Note that we can simplify this to a 1D problem by considering `y-x` as one variable: "we start at `y-x = 0` and move such that `y-x` either increases or decreases by 1 each move with equal chance and we are interested when `y-x = 1`. This means we can consider the 1D case by subbing in `z=y-x`.

Comment: "simulating multiple paths" sounds like an understatement when you're simulating *all* paths

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode k now I consider it simulating "all possible paths" :)

Comment: [recursive formula](https://tio.run/##lZLdisIwEIXv@xRzIyaxtk1VWATfY@9CrIkG6iSkcV2fvpvaKrjUZTtXYXLm5zuMu4WTxdWH821rzs76AGcZTslBaXDe7uXe1CbchNXiahANHoXUQXlRonD1pRFcNEG5hmB613fCs/3qdNr6q/QH2EGRbeg2gRhehYtHIN2MTMsqWG9kTUqGNP@VG8ksOIV7myHYm5GM9VoGhC/HJZTFkclkTPH5T1CjAWEXM9vnwgP7ePGLO1M3WnL6agtZM1yWFHJ4GPFm5b8civbEZ8QwCF7iUZFVCrwoBkL17VQVIvS0M6EDaXOppxZ3qH258wZDf0SmqWrbKNJ3TIe1aArzWcY3GuaRcQUzIP1HCg9h2cHHw4vmPX3KYU1p2/4A) for f(n,x) based on f(n-1,x). If I remembered the convergence tests, I might've been able to finish it...

Answer (score 1):

Vectorisation would result in much faster code, approximately ~90K times faster. Here is the function that would return step to hit `y=1-x` line starting from `(0,0)` and trajectory generation on the 2D grid with unit steps .

```py
import numpy as np

def _random_walk_2D(sim_steps):
    """ Walk on 2D unit steps
        return  x_sim, y_sim, trajectory, number_of_steps_first_hit to y=1-x """
    random_moves_x = np.insert(np.random.choice([1,0,-1], sim_steps), 0, 0)
    random_moves_y = np.insert(np.random.choice([1,0,-1], sim_steps), 0, 0)
    x_sim = np.cumsum(random_moves_x)
    y_sim = np.cumsum(random_moves_y)
    trajectory = np.array((x_sim,y_sim)).T
    y_hat = 1-x_sim # checking if hit y=1-x
    y_hit = y_hat-y_sim
    hit_steps = np.where(y_hit == 0)
    number_of_steps_first_hit = -1
    if hit_steps[0].shape[0] > 0:
        number_of_steps_first_hit = hit_steps[0][0]
    return x_sim, y_sim, trajectory, number_of_steps_first_hit
```

if `number_of_steps_first_hit` is -1 it means trajectory does not hit the line.

A longer simulation and repeating might give the average behaviour, but the following one tells if it does not escape to Infiniti it hits line on average ~84 steps.

```
sim_steps= 5*10**3 # 5K steps
#Repeat 
nrepeat = 40000
hit_step = [_random_walk_2D(sim_steps)[3] for _ in range(nrepeat)]
hit_step = [h for h in hit_step if h > -1]
np.mean(hit_step) #  ~84 step
```

Much longer `sim_steps` will change the result though.

**PS:**
Good exercise, hope that this wasn't a homework, if it was homework, please cite this answer if it is used.

**Edit**
As discussed in the comments current `_random_walk_2D` works for 8-directions. To restrict it to cardinal direction we could do the following filtering:

```
cardinal_x_y = [(t[0], t[1]) for t in zip(random_moves_x, random_moves_y)  
                if np.abs(t[0]) != np.abs(t[1])]
random_moves_x = [t[0] for t in cardinal_x_y]
random_moves_y = [t[1] for t in cardinal_x_y]
```

though this would slow it down the function a bit but still will be super fast compare to `for loop` solutions.

Comment: using `choice([-1,0,1]` for both x and y means you can move diagonally or not move at all right? If you want to restrict to 4 cardinal directions you probably either want to do complex like I did or something like `moves = choice([-1,-2,1,2]..).. x = (moves == 1) - (moves == -1); y = (moves == 2) - (moves == -2)` to filter out x and y in terms of a single call to random, or just simulate in 1D which works just as well.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, good point. Having zero in `choice([-1,0,1]`, we move in 8 directions, instead of 4. We can remove 0 from `choice` if we want to restrict to 4.

Comment: well that would restrict it to `(1,1)`, `(-1,1)`, `(-1,1)`, and `(-1,-1)` which aren't the actual cardinal directions, in fact doing that means you can never reach the line `y=1-x` from the origin since that requires moving 1 step away.... actually that means that if you step over the line with your current code it doesn't count as a hit right?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, you are right. I didn't notice the restriction on cardinal direction.  This code works for 8 directions, including diagonals. For cardinal directions `(0,1)`, `(1, 0)`, `(-1,0)` and `(0,-1)` we would need to filter out `x_sim` and `y_sim`, as you have already suggested.